# meteor iron-router with polymer paper-button not routing and iron-router layout template events not firing

Tags: meteor, mobile-safari, polymer, iron-router

[Live Demo, source link at bottom](http://paper-button-routing-prob.meteor.com)

Problem 1:
I'm using Meteor 1.0 and my initial problem is that in iOS Safari, the `<a>` tag does not route to the `href` path.  It routes fine in all other desktop browsers.

The `<a>` tag is wrapped around a `<paper-button>` element.

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'vis1'}}" class="non-a">
    <paper-button unresolved>home</paper-button>
</a>
```

This is the way polymer-project.org has implemented their buttons.  I found that if I remove the `<paper-button>` and just have the `<a>` by itself, the page will route correctly in iOS Safari.  I can't figure out why this would only be a problem in mobile Safari.

Problem 2:
While trying to debug this I tried attaching a `'click'` event to the `<a>`s (while viewing it in safari's ios simulator inspector) using

```
Template.navbar.events({
    'click .navigation':function(e){
        console.log('click on navbar');
    },
    'click a':function(e){
        //e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('click on a tag');
    }
});
```

However, none of the click events console.log in either mobile Safari, Safari 8.0 or FF 34.0, but do in Chrome 39.0 and Opera.  I can't figure out why this would be different either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that polymer is the issue.  I removed all occurences of polymer elements in the templates and the `'click'` events still would not fire (on Safari and FF).  What finally fixed it was executing

```
`meteor remove ecywne:polymer`
```

This makes sense that it is polymer-related since Chrome and Opera don't seem to have a problem.

Addyo's response to [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767115/polymer-elements-in-a-meteor-app) seems to hint that there is an incompatibility between meteor and polymer.

I'm not sure where the conflict is, but I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/ecwyne/meteor-polymer/issues/19) on the meteor-polymer page.