# Adding and using Polymer in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer

How does one make Polymer work in Meteor? I have tried to use atmosphere packages ecwyne:polymer-elements and ecwyne:polymer but I can't get anything working. No observable changes. No one seems to have done a tutorial on the same out there. I am definitely doing it wrong.

Would someone be kind enough to break the whole process down for a newbie? I will highly appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just forgot to add the link into your head elements.
If you want to use one polymer elements you have to add it in your `<head>`

I made a boiler-plate, you can have a look at it, it works (meteor+polymer), I can made a better tutoriel if I have some feedbacks, I have one with only polymer and meteor and I'm working with a version with accounts on it also.

Here are the links :

- [meteor+polymer](https://github.com/Voyag3r/meteor-polymer-boilertemplate) Very simple, a toolbar and a menu.
- [meteor+polymer+accounts](https://github.com/Voyag3r/meteor-accounts-polymer) Still working on it, works except for socials buttons but I'm on it
- [meteor+polymer+accounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/boilerplates/tree/master/polymer) Same as above but from the original meteor-useraccounts team

Comment: I like your initiative. Let me check out the repos

Comment: I finally solved it: [Check on my answer on @jamstooks question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28351086/3414315)